# Best way of using ObservableCollection in a multi threaded environment

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, observablecollection

Ok from below which one is best approach or any other better ways ?

Both are working (credits not belongs to me)

```
public static MTObservableCollection<string> ocEventsCollection = new MTObservableCollection<string>();

    public static void AddMsgToEvents(string srMessage)
    {
        lock (ocEventsCollection)
            ocEventsCollection.Insert(0, srMessage);

    }

    public class MTObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
    {
        public override event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;
        protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged = this.CollectionChanged;
            if (CollectionChanged != null)
                foreach (NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler nh in CollectionChanged.GetInvocationList())
                {
                    DispatcherObject dispObj = nh.Target as DispatcherObject;
                    if (dispObj != null)
                    {
                        Dispatcher dispatcher = dispObj.Dispatcher;
                        if (dispatcher != null && !dispatcher.CheckAccess())
                        {
                            dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                                (Action)(() => nh.Invoke(this,
                                    new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset))),
                                DispatcherPriority.DataBind);
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                    nh.Invoke(this, e);
                }
        }
    }
```

And the second approach

```
public static ObservableCollection<string> ocEventsCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>();



public static void AddMsgToEvents(string srMessage)
{
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        ocEventsCollection.Insert(0, srMessage);
    }));
}
```

Comment: take a look at caliburn micro'd BindableCollection<T>

Comment: What do you mean by "best approach"? Which is more "thread safe"?

Comment: If you looking at thread safety and using framework 4.5 why not use the tools provided out of the box? Take a look at `BindingOperations` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingoperations(v=vs.110).aspx) and using the `EnableCollectionSynchronization` method or use `BlockingCollection<T>()` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx)